# Mysql sorting Hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, hierarchical

I have a question and working last week with this and couldnt solve yet.. I can query submenus with join but i cant order it.

I have a table like this

```
| id   |  name           |  parent | order  |    
|-------------------------------------------|
| 1    | menu1           |  0      |   1    |
| 2    | submenu1        |  1      |   2    |
| 3    | submenu2        |  1      |   1    |
| 4    | subsubmenu      |  2      |   1    |
| 5    | subsubsubmenu:) |  4      |   1    |
| 6    | menu2           |  0      |   3    |
| 7    | menu3           |  0      |   2    |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

I wanna get something like this.

```
| - menu1
      | - submenu2
      | - submenu1
              | - subsubmenu
                       | - subsubsubmenu:)
| - menu3
| - menu2
```

Can anybody give me an idea how can handle this?  Thank you

Comment: It depends on what type of result you want to get, do you want to get submenus in a flat list or as a separate columns. Can you provide an example of query that you use?

Comment: I need it in flat list. Maybe with level column.

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: yes i used query here http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: would be so easy if MySQL finally arrived in the 21st century and supported recursive queries.

Answer (score 1):

I have studied http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/ and found a solution for your problem. I guess you already have your solution but for any other who is searching for same solution I am answering here.

My solution will work for relational Tables also as we can't set zero (0) in parent field in relational table. It will be NULL and my solution works perfectly for relational tables also.

### The Function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id(value INT) RETURNS INTEGER
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE _parent INT;
    DECLARE _rank INT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @id = NULL;

    SET _parent = @id;
    SET _rank = 0;

    IF @id IS NULL THEN
            RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    LOOP
        SET @innerrank = 0;
        SELECT p.id 
        INTO   @id
        FROM   (
                SELECT   id, @innerrank := @innerrank+1 AS rank 
                FROM     yourTable 
                WHERE    COALESCE(parent, 0) = _parent 
                ORDER BY yourField
                ) p 
        WHERE   p.rank > _rank LIMIT 0, 1;
        IF @id IS NOT NULL OR _parent = @start_with THEN
                SET @level = @level + 1;
                RETURN @id;
        END IF;
        SET @level := @level - 1;
        SET @innerrank = 0;
        SELECT COALESCE(p.parent, 0), p.rank
        INTO   _parent, _rank
        FROM   (
                SELECT id, parent, @innerrank := @innerrank+1 AS rank
                FROM    yourTable
                WHERE   COALESCE(parent, 0) = (
                    SELECT COALESCE(parent, 0) FROM yourTable WHERE id = _parent
                    ) 
                ORDER BY yourField
               ) p
        WHERE p.id = _parent;
    END LOOP;       
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Please replace `yourTable` with your table name and `yourField` with your field name by which you want to sort your data.

### The Query

```
SELECT ou.* FROM (
    SELECT hi.id, parent, yourField FROM (
        SELECT hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id(id) AS id, 
            @level AS level 
            FROM (
                SELECT @start_with := 0, @id := @start_with, @level := 0
                 ) vars, yourTable 
            WHERE @id IS NOT NULL
        ) ho 
    JOIN yourTable hi ON hi.id = ho.id
) ou
```

Please replace `yourTable` with your table name and `yourField` with your field name which you want to display.

This will produce the result as you required. I tested it and works well.

Here is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d060d/2 to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a single query.  Just use recursion in your scripting language of choice

```
class Hierarchy

    function __construct(db)
        db = db.connect
        this.stmt = db.prepare "SELECT name FROM Hierarchy WHERE parent = ?"
        this.tree = {}
    end

    function getHierarchyFromParent(parent = 0, tree = null)
        tree = this.tree if tree is null
        while result = this.stmt.execute(parent).fetch
            tree[result.name] = {
                children: this.getHierarchyFromParent result.id tree[result.name]
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes that is how i was using it before but it is really slow whit big datas. I need to get all menus and submenus with 1 query.

Comment: @MücahitBüyükyılmaz even if it was one query it wouldn't necessarily be faster .. an alternative would be to fetch all rows at once with one query and then create the parent/child associations by looping over the list twice

Comment: @ExplosionPills is right, if you do not want to have sub-select queries and do not want to have a flat ordering in the table, the only option is recursive ordering in application level (or database level via procedures)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer - you want the results in a flat list. In that case I would say that the most efficient way is to make sure that you change your order strategy, you will avoid unnecessary complexity and overhead when selecting items.
You would solve the issue if your ordering would be based on the flat list too:

```
| id   |  name           |  parent | order  |    
|-------------------------------------------|
| 1    | menu1           |  0      |   1    |
| 2    | submenu1        |  1      |   2    |
| 3    | submenu2        |  1      |   3    |
| 4    | subsubmenu      |  2      |   4    |
| 5    | subsubsubmenu:) |  4      |   5    |
| 6    | menu2           |  0      |   6    |
| 7    | menu3           |  0      |   7    |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

Implementing such ordering is not very hard.

Comment: Actually i tought this but there is a column for department i didnt write it. I am using this table for our university website and about 110 department using this table for their menu. It would be ordered separate for each department.

Comment: it does not matter how many menu items or departments will use this table, you can still use flat ordering, which will make selecting very efficient. I don't see an advantage of making complicated select statements in frontend instead of keeping a little bit more complicated insert/update in backend.

Comment: @AurelijusValeiša interesting thought. but, don't you think order for menu2 and menu3 should be 1 ? Or have I misunderstood it